# URL Rewriting in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I'm wondering what is the best way to handle URL in MVC. For example, in my application I have a `PageController` can link to `/website/Page/Index/3` or `/website/Page/home`.  The menu is built dynamically with Html.ActionLink() and T4MVC based on the incoming urls so I don't have anything hardcoded.

Now what I want to do is to point my url and links to something more SEO friendly like, for example, `/website/our-company/` and it can also have children like `/website/our-company/location/` or `/website/our-company/employees/`. You get the idea.

All my Pages are saved to the BD and I have `FriendlyUrl` and `parentId` properties in my object.

What's is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Better have a look at : - [**ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview (C#)**](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-05-cs.aspx)

Comment: I now this stuff but I'm not quite sure how I can do what I'm trying to do up here, Is it possible that my Html.ActionLink() will redirect to /website/our-company/location/ when I point to MVC.Page.Index(12)? And what does my route should look like since I don't want the "Page", witch is the controller, part in my url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took a look at http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-23-cs.aspx and I got it working. More simple than I thought...

My routes :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("Pages3", "{url1}/{url2}/{url3}", MVC.Page.RedirectTo(), new { url1 = "", url2 = "", url3 = "" });
    routes.MapRoute("Pages2", "{url1}/{url2}", MVC.Page.RedirectTo(), new { url1 = "", url2 = "", url3 = "" });
    routes.MapRoute("Pages1", "{url1}", MVC.Page.RedirectTo(), new { url1 = "", url2 = "", url3 = "" });
}
```

And now my controller :

```
public virtual ActionResult RedirectTo(string url1, string url2, string url3)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url1)) return Home();

    var pageModel = new PageModel();
    pageModel.CurrentPage = _pageRepo.GetByUrl(url1, url2, url3);
    BuildMenusAndBreadCrumb(pageModel);
    ViewData.Model = pageModel;

    return View(Views.Index);
}
```

And here's how I render a link (my menu exemple) :

```
<div class="header_menu_content">
<ul id="main_menu_header">
    <% foreach(var item in Model) {%>
        <% if(item.Children != null){ %>
            <li><%= Html.ActionLink(item.Title, MVC.Page.RedirectTo(item.Url, "", ""))%>
            <ul>
            <% foreach (var child in item.Children){ %>
                <li><%= Html.ActionLink(child.Title, MVC.Page.RedirectTo(item.Url, child.Url, "")) %></li>
            <% }%>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <% } else { %>
            <li class="nochild"><%= Html.ActionLink(item.Title, MVC.Page.RedirectTo(item.Url, "", "")) %></li>
        <% } %>
    <%} %>
</ul>
```

Works perfectly for my needs! If you have any question or comments don't be shy! I'm not sure it's the best way to do it but I'm happy with it!

Note that the route order is important and also, if you don't put the default value and are in a page where url2 = something (site/section/page) then all your link will point to site/newsection?url2=page took me a while to figure out why that url2 param was there but now it's all right!

Comment: Can you specify your namespaces?  Where is MVC.Page?   If MVC a controller?