# URl rewriting in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hy

i had write below code

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home", // Route name
            "", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
                   "Controller_Action", // Route name
                   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                   new { id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
        foreach (var route in GetDefaultRoutes())
        {
            routes.Add(route);
        }
        routes.MapRoute(
            "UserPage", // Route name
            "{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Get" } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }




    private static IEnumerable<Route> GetDefaultRoutes()
    {
        //My controllers assembly (can be get also by name)
        Assembly assembly = typeof(test1.Controllers.HomeController).Assembly;
        // get all the controllers that are public and not abstract
        var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller)) && t.IsPublic && !t.IsAbstract);
        // run for each controller type
        foreach (var type in types)
        {

            //Get the controller name - each controller should end with the word Controller
            string controller = type.Name.Substring(0, type.Name.IndexOf("Controller"));
            // create the default
            RouteValueDictionary routeDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary
                                               {
                                                   {"controller", controller}, // the controller name
                                                   {"action", "index"} // the default method
                                               };
            yield return new Route(controller, routeDictionary, new MvcRouteHandler());
        }
    }
```

i am new to mvc,i want to rewrite my url somthing like this,suppose my url is like www.myhouse.com/product/index/1 then i want to display only www.myhouse.com/prduct-name for better seo performance,i am using mvc4 beta,i had also one through [URL Rewriting in .Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375256/url-rewriting-in-net-mvc) but it is not working for me....

but i don't know how to pass pass value to this method.

Comment: Why do you use "mvc" (name of language-independent design pattern) to describe ASP.NET MVC 4 framework ? Are you one of the people, who calls the IE icon on desktop "the interent" too ?

Comment: this is not kind of to call the IE icon on desktop "the interent" ,in mvc this possible i dont know the way that's why i asked you...

Comment: You can use url rewriting (attribute rewriting ) please check the link i have given 
http://sreerejith.blogspot.in/2015/07/url-rewriting-in-mvc-4-attribute-routing.html

Answer (score 2):

After lots of searching on the internet, i got my solution

add below code to `global.asax`

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Home", // Route name
            "", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
           "jats", // Route name
           "{jats}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Content" } // Parameter defaults
         );
```

then add below code to view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("test", "Content", new { jats= "test-test" })
```

add below code to `HomeController`:

```
public ActionResult Content(string jats)
{
    return View();
}
```

then you done...now URL is same as you pass in query string...so your controller name and query string parameter will not display.

Comment: what about parameters?