# How to show Clean URL's but still pass data to contoller Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, clean-urls

I am working on ASP.net MVC 2.0 Web Application in C#. My Question is:

I have an URL Like this:

```
http://localhost:3281/Home/Edit/6
```

I am passing data to Controller in the URL. Is it possible to get an URL some thing like this:

```
  http://localhost:3281/Home/Index
```

But, still will be able to pass the data to controllers action method.

I doubt whether my question is meaningless..but still want to make it cleared.

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible , for my advice use Url rewriting
[URL Rewriting in .Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375256/url-rewriting-in-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You can define default values in a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "Home/Index/{id}",
            defaults: new 
                        { 
                            controller = "Home", 
                            action = "Index", 
                            id = 6  // default value for the id parameter
                        });
```

If you use this url `http://localhost:3281/Home/Index` with this action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

The `id` parameter will be 6.