# MVC 4, create URL dynamic for pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, dynamic, routeconfig

Let's say I have a model called artikel.
this article contains Html "body" text. and a one word title.

Then I want to make a system, where i can use one view to render all of "Article" model's body content.

but use the articles Title prop. to create a Url for the site.

So if i got 2 articles.
one titled "About", and one with the title "Contact"

i would end up with Url like 
"site/About"
And 
"site/Contact"

And since I'm trying to make this from a data source, I need some way to do this dynamic. so i can't just make controllers for each artikel. (Which would be bad if i got many articles anyways)

I been trying in my RouteConfig to setup a mapRoute. but can't find anyway which would do this.

I search the net for it, an tried those solutions.

http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-url-rewriting-and-url-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-mvc5-with-examples

[URL Rewriting in .Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375256/url-rewriting-in-net-mvc)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h405AbJyiH4

https://forums.asp.net/t/2094370.aspx?How+To+Create+URL+Rewrite+In+ASP+NET+C+using+MVC+

But no luck.
Anyone that know's how to do this, or that can help me in the right direction.?

Comment: check this article may be That's what you want or give you another idea

Comment: @AliBesharatinia sorry. but did you forget to post the link?

Comment: The problem is, that url `site/About` would override any other. How do you know About is not a controller?

Comment: Is it good enough to have example.com/artikel/About and example.com/artikel/Contact etc? or do you need example.com/About. If it's the former you can have an action that gets the article name as a route parameter. You could then retrieve the appropriate page from your data source and render it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem, for example you can set Artikel to be the default controller, creating new route, or a custom route, etc. I recommend to include artikel in the url `website/artikel/pagename` for finding the articles.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Artikel",
        url: "artikel/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Artikel", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    //default and other routes go here, after Artikel
}
```

**In Artikel controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    Artikel model = Database.GetArticle(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Artikel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

**And the view:**

```
@model MyApplication.Models.Artikel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<span>@Model.Body</span>
```

Comment: I used this in combination with som URL rewrite.